# How to change product pages structure , layout for multiple categories in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, category, layout, theme

I want to change product page structure and layout by categories wise, high customization. For example if I have 3 categories then it should have 3 different category page view.

(whatever I change should reflect on each category page).

Comment: Could you explain it properly means could you share some designs 
Because Magento basically provides 4 different type layout view you could set it from the admin side but if you  want more view than you need to create more layouts type

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused as to what your requirements are, it sounds like you want to customise the layout for every category page?

If so the easiest way to achieve this is to use layout XML.

1. Create `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`
2. Make your layout changes here.
3. Clear Magento cache if it's enabled

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.view.container" destination="content" before="category.products" />

        <referenceBlock name="category.view.container">
            <block
                class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                name="layered.nav.trigger"
                as="layeredNavTrigger"
                template="Magento_Catalog::category/layered-nav-trigger.phtml"
                before="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.sticky.banner" template="Magento_Catalog::sticky-banner.phtml" before="footer.social">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="category.sticky.banner.block">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">category-sticky-banner</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here I am moving 1 element and adding a few new blocks to every category page.

Comment: this will reflect for every page

Comment: This will only affect category pages, if you want to affect every single page you need to add the file `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this ,you will require to create extra layout with creating custom **module.Magento2** default provided layouts are as follows.

```
1 column
2 columns with left bar
2 columns with right bar
3 columns
```

So you need to create more layouts by using Empty layout and need to choose these layout in category Design section.

[image]

For creating layout,you can take help from: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11136/24878

Hope this will help you.

Comment: when im updating any column except "1 column layout" it will just adding more elements in 1 column layout.  that is its updating to "1 column layout "